# Landscape Server - How to change default "No Reply" alert email address

Tags: 16.04, server, email, postfix, landscape

I  currently have a working setup of a landscape server connected to 10 webservers. All is working fine, and emails are being sent properly for alerts. Although, I am receiving alerts from noreply@mydomain.com instead of my own email. This is causing a loop back with my ticketing system (which does not allow replies) in which both of the 'noreply' emails are generating responses to one another. Where can I enter the credentials for my own email instead of using this default 'noreply' email?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust this address on the settings page.

```
Dashboard -> Settings -> System email address
```

[image: Screenshot of Landscape Tool]